# Because of the Facebook sdks v2, is it now impossible to get all of a users friends list in Swift?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, swift

I was reading up on here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/friends?locale=en_GB that the user_friends permission can only return a list of friends who also use the app. All I am trying to do is get all of a users friends' profile pictures. Is there some workaround to this in swift?

Comment: If the API doesn't give you all friends it doesn't matter which language you are using. You are correct you can only get app friends

Comment: That seems like a real loss of some basic functionality

Comment: Or like a really nice change for users that care about their privacy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In combination with getting a list of friends who use the app, you can also get a list of the "invitable friends." These are the user's friends who have not allowed the app.

Here is a link to the documentation
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/invitable-friends/v2.2?locale=en_GB

Comment: Thats only for games though.